# Problema con la cache del buscador del datatable en Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Defino un datatable con buscador("searching": true), pero cuando carga en la pagina, el buscador se le asigna por defecto un valor de la cache del navegador. Por ejemplo carga bien, pero despues en el filtro de búsqueda se le agrega la palabra de un login automatica que antes se ingresaba, es como si algo estuviese escribiendo automáticamente en el input de búsqueda, lo cual hace que acote los resultados.

Dejo el codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    table_cotizacion = $('#table_cotizacion').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        //"bInfo": false,
        //"bPaginate": false,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 45, 75, 105, 135, 165, 195, 225, 255, 285], [10, 45, 75, 105, 135, 165, 195, 225, 255, 285]],
        "language": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            },
            "paginate": {
                "previous": "Anterior",
                "next": "Siguiente"
            }
        },
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        }
    });

<table id="table_cotizacion" class="table table-striped table-bordered tableSection table_consulta" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%">Número</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Fecha</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Rut</th>
            <th style="width: 50%">Nombre</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% int i = 0;
           foreach (var item in Model)
           {
               i++;
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%:item.numero %>
            </td>
            <td>
<%:item.fecha %>            
            </td>
            <td>
                <%:item.rutcompleto %>
            </td>
                        <td>
                <%:item.proveedor %>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Existirá alguna forma de impedir que se llene automaticamente el buscador, algo como que borre la cache de los inputs de busqueda del datatable. 
Desde ya,gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Supongo que debes de tener un formulario donde tienes los inputs de la búsqueda de la tabla, siendo así puedes probar esto:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" id="text1">
 <input type="text" id="text2">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias @Johan Stiven Hernandez Osorio por responder, pero el input de busqueda se crea solo al indicarle la propiedad searching": true como indica la pregunta.

https://datatables.net/